# Se muestra el código HTML al enviar correo con PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, phpmailer

Tengo un formulario en el que se capturan los datos en JS con AJAX, los envío a una función de PHP para enviar un correo electrónico con PHPMailer, el script me trabaja sin problemas y envía el correo.

El problema se da cuando me retorna la respuesta desde el PHP, debería de enviar un JSON con un estado para validar, pero me retorna todo el código HTML que compone el mensaje junto con el JSON, haciendo que en la función AJAX no pueda leer el JSON para validar la respuesta y mostrando todo el código HTML en la consola, así no haya ningún console.log o algo que le indique que lo muestre.

Función AJAX:

```
$('body').on('submit', '#recover', function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var dataJSON = {
    modulo: "login",
    accion: "recover_form",
    form:   $('#recover').serializeJSON();
    }    

$.ajax({

    url: "scripts.php",
    data: dataJSON,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(data) {

        //console.log('loading...');
        var resp = respuestaBox('loading');

        if (resp.estado != 0) {

            $('.msj-responde').html(resp.html);

        }else{

            $('.msj-responde').html(resp.msj);

        }

    },
    success: function(data) {

        $('.msj-responde').html('');
            //console.table(data);
           
            if (data.estado == 1) {

                var resp = respuestaBox('success',data.msj);
                $('.msj-responde').html(resp.html);
                document.getElementById('recover').reset();

            }else{

                var resp = respuestaBox('error',data.msj);
                $('.msj-responde').html(resp.html);

            }

        },
        error: function(data) {

        }

    });

});
```

Parte de la función PHP:

```php
        if ($this->o_mail->envioCorreo($correo,$consult['nombre'],$asunto,$mail)) {
    
        $responde = array('estado'  => 1, 
            'msj'   => 'Se ha enviado un mensaje para la recuperación de la contraseña al correo '.$correo, 
            'type'  => 'success');
    
    }else{
    
        $responde = array('estado'  => -1, 
            'msj'   => 'Error al enviar el correo de recuperación de la contraseña.', 
            'type'  => 'error');
    
    }
    
    return json_encode($responde, true);

#La funcion envioCorreo(); es envio los datos del destinatario y el codigo HTML del mensaje a enviar por correo.

    include("phpmail/class.phpmailer.php");
    
    class Mail{
    
        function envioCorreo($correo_destino, $nombre_remitente, $asunto, $mensaje, $nombre_destino = '', $nombre_archivo = '', $ruta = '',$idcliente = '',$accion = 0)
        {
    
            $email = new PHPMailer();
            $email->IsSMTP();
            $email->SMTPAuth = true;    
            $email->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // protocolo de seguridad
            $email->Host = "*****.com";// host de gmail
            $email->Port = 465; // puertos seguros ssl/tls (465,587) 
            $email->Username = "*****@*****.com"; //correo del remitente
            $email->Password = "*****";  // contraseña remitente
            $email->FromName = $nombre_remitente; //nombre del remitente
            $email->From = "*****@*****.com"; // correo y nombre del remitente
            $email->Subject = $asunto; // asunto del correo
            $email->Body = $mensaje;    // mensaje del correo
            $email->MsgHTML($mensaje);  // mensaje del correo
                
            for ($i=0; $i < count($correo_destino) ; $i++) { 
                
                $email->AddAddress($correo_destino[$i]); // correo y nombre del destinatario    
    
            }
    
            $email->IsHTML(true); // Establece el cuerpo del mensaje
    
            if($email->Send()){
                return true;
            }else{
                //die($email->ErrorInfo);
                return false;
            }
    
        }
    
    };
```

[image: Respuesta en la consola del navegador]

al no poder leer el JSON no puedo mostrarle el mensaje al usuario que el correo fue enviado exitosamente, ademas que al mostrar el mensaje HTMl en la consola, es muy inseguro ya que ahi se ve el enlace de reestablecimiento de la contgraseña, que es el objetivo del script.

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda, no se por donde mas solucionar este problema, he quitado todos los console.log() del JS y los die() del PHP.

Comment: Que te devuelve si pones un die antes del return responde?

Comment: Si coloco un die() antes del return, igual me muestra el HTML en la consola, al parecer lo está retornando así se pare la función antes del return.

Comment: Prueba únicamente el PHP, utilizando herramientas como postman x ejemplo. Así verás si el html o el resultado del PHP es correcto o no. Dependiendo de esas pruebas puede que el problema este en PHP o en jsvascript

Comment: Prueba únicamente el PHP, utilizando herramientas como postman x ejemplo. Así verás si el html o el resultado del PHP es correcto o no. Dependiendo de esas pruebas puede que el problema este en PHP o en jsvascript

Comment: Hice las pruebas, aislé la función por completo en el PHP, para que solo enviara el correo y la ejecute a través de Postman, sigue dando la misma respuesta :(, también probé con el servidor de pruebas local donde desarrollo que está con MAMP y el servidor de producción que está en una cuenta de Hostgator por si sería algún problema de configuración del servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude solucionar el problema. Buscando mucho daban la solución de modificar unas líneas de la librería de phpMailer, pero lo ideal sin tener que modificar nada de la librería fue reemplazando las siguientes líneas

tenía al inicio de la función:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
```

y lo reemplace por:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false; 
$mail->do_debug = 0;
```

y así evité que retornara la respuesta del servidor junto con el mensaje HTML que era lo que estaba retornando phpMailer

la función completa quedó de esta forma:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class phpMail{

    function envioCorreo($correo_destino, $nombre_remitente, $asunto, $mensaje, $nombre_destino = '', $nombre_archivo = '', $ruta = '',$idcliente = '',$accion = 0)
    {

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        try {

            $mail->SMTPDebug = false; 
            $mail->do_debug = 0; 
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            
            $mail->Host       = 'mail.*****.com ';               
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
            $mail->Username   = '*****@*****.com';                 
            $mail->Password   = '*****';                         
            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    

            $mail->setFrom('*****@*****v.com', 'Valenciadev');

            $mail->addAddress($correo_destino, $nombre_remitente);      

            $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
            $mail->Subject = $asunto;
            $mail->Body    = $mensaje;
          
            $mail->send();

            return true;

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            //die("Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}");
            return false;

        }

    }
};
```

Dejando el die() comentado en caso de error, para poder activarlo si sucede algun problema, para que phpMailer muestre la información del fallo.